# Linux virtual server, direct routing (LVS/DR) on VPN

Tags: linux, virtualization, routing

Is it possible to set up Linux Virtual Server on VPN?

[image: From http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/VS-DRouting.html]

The real servers should lie on the same LAN segment. I want the real server to be a non-LAN server connected to the Internet. Could it be possible? I thought to put Linux director and real server on VPN.

Comment: I believe your description tries to complicate a simple thing (correct me if I misunderstood your intentions). Isn't OpenVPN bridged setup what you need? With such setup OpenVPN connection serves just as a virtual ethernet cable - no routing, no additional VPN addressing, etc.

Comment: I want the following: HTTP client connects to host X (Apache); X holds half-connection with the client and makes host Y to make half-connection to the client; thus, client thinks it gets data from host X but actually data is transferred from Y. Such a configuration is realized by Linux Virtual Server via Direct Routing. The requirement for LVS/DR is that Director (host X) and real server (host Y) must be on the same physical segment. I want to emulate this segment by some technology, e.g. VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like OpenVPN in bridging mode can solve your problem. I've used such configurations in the past, and can confirm this works as expected, emulating an ethernet cable and without forcing any additions subnets, etc.